# Writing information in another file using awk script

Tags: awk, files, io-redirection

I have an awk script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{}
{
   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        sum+=$i; #sum of 3 numbers in a row
        printf "Hello %d%s, %s %s, %d\n",NR,OFS, $1,$2,j;j=0
   print > "hellofile1"
}
END{}
```

I want the .awk file to have the following output in hellofile1

```
        1st field  2nd field
Hello 1  ...        ...
Hello 2  ...        ...
Hello 3  ...        ...
```

However when I run it as: awk -f hf.awk hello it brings up the error of '>' and '>>'. 
P.S. The $1 outside of the print command refers to the hello file as an argument.

Comment: apart from @kusalanada's answer (which cover it all), you almost make it. in awk multiple `>` will truncate and create (first invocation), then append (subsequent invication).

Comment: @archemar. Actually, awk retains the file open throughout. You can use > on every output, and it will just append. Only the first > or >> encountered for a specific file will truncate (or not) the existing file, and either will create it if needed.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant yes, that's exactly what Archemar said :) That the 1st invocation of `>` will truncate, while the subsequent ones will append.

Comment: @terdon. The OP was edited while I was making that comment, and originally contained both > and >>. So I read arche comment as saying the append syntax was necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can't redirect the output of a block in `awk` (this refers to [an earlier version of the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/560115/1)). You also need to double quote the name of the output file (this also refers to [an earlier version of the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/560115/1)).  Empty `BEGIN` and `END` blocks may be removed completely.

Instead, if you just want to prefix all the lines of a file with `Hello N`, where `N` is the integer corresponding to the current line number (this is just what I'm able to infer that you want to do, and the code was modified substantially at least once during the writing this answer; you could obviously modify this to do whatever you actually need to do), use

```awk
{
    printf "Hello %d%s%s\n", NR, OFS, $0 >"hellofile1"

    # or:  print "Hello " NR, $0 >"hellofile1"
}
```

This prints each line of the input file to the file `hellofile1`, prefixed by the string `Hello` , the line number, and the output field separator (a space by default).

The output file `hellofile1` will be truncated due to the `>`, but `awk` keeps the file open for writing until it is either explicitly closed (which does not happen here), or until the program ends, so all the program's output would be printed correctly to the file (subsequent `print >` calls would append to the already opened file).

Another way to do this:

```awk
{
    for (i = NF; i >= 1; --i)
        $(i+1) = $i

    $1 = sprintf("Hello %d", NR)    # or:  $1 = "Hello " NR
    print >"hellofile1"
}
```

This moves the existing fields "to the right" by one field and inserts the `Hello N` string as the first field in the record. Then it prints the record to the output file.  Note that this re-forms the records and separates their fields by `OFS` (a space by default) in the output.

You would use this as

```
$ awk -f script.awk myfile
```

where `myfile` is some file that you would want to use as input.

Comment: Why not just `awk '{print "Hello",NR,$0}' inFile > outFile`? Or, if you want awk to do the redirection `awk '{print "Hello",NR,$0 > outFile}' inFile`. Why bother with `printf "Hello %d%s%s\n", NR, OFS, $0`?

Comment: And why `$1 = sprintf("Hello %d", NR)` instead of `$1 = "Hello "NR`? Am I just using GNUisms without knowing it? Are your approaches more portable to non-gawk implementations?

Comment: @terdon The user want to use a redirection inside `awk` it seems, so that's why I did it that way. As for the `printf`, `print "Hello " NR, $0` would also have worked, but `print "Hello", NR, $0` would have separated `Hello` and `NR` by `OFS` which we don't control in this code.

Comment: @terdon Hmm... Maybe it's just me that has an aversion against concatenating strings?  I'll add your suggestions in as comments in the code.  Would `NR` concatenated with `Hello ` be formatted by `CONVFMT`? The `printf` and `sprintf` variations avoids that (edit: it's not affected by `CONVFMT`).

Comment: I don't understand. You're already separating `Hello` and `NR` by `OFS`, in your `printf`, it's just that you chose to do it manually, explicitly, instead of letting awk's default `print` behavior do it for you. Since we're not touching `OFS`, we know it's a space in this code. `print "Hello " NR, $0` would add an extra space if OFS is also a space.

Comment: @terdon We don't know it's a space unless we rely on the user not changing it with `-v`. `print "Hello " NR, $0` would not add an _extra_ space apart from the `OFS` that  `print` inserts between fields.

Comment: @Kusalananda I run this but I get a message error that says that hellofile1 does not exist. Please see the edited post

Comment: @user25 By changing the code in the question, you invalidated part of my answer. Furthermore, I can't reproduce your error. Your new code just prints the input to the `hellofile1` file, while producing some other output in the terminal. It is unclear what you want to achieve (you haven't mentioned this at all).

Comment: I just want the hellofile1 to have the output above, however, hellofile1 doesn't match the correct output  on the terminal. Instead it has the containings of the first file

Comment: @user25 Do you even have to worry about `hellofie1` in the `awk` code at all? Why not just print as ordinary and then redirect to an output file in the shell when you run the `awk` script?

Comment: @Kusalananda I want to create the file within the awk script because I want to see the redirection being done in the script and not from the command line. And I cannot understand why it won't redirect the output to the ```hellofile1```.

Comment: @user25 You are simply not printing to the output file with the `printf`.

Comment: @Kusalananda you mean that the command needs to be like this?: ``` printf > "hellofile1"

Comment: @user25 Every `print` or `printf` statement that you want to redirect needs to be redirected.

Comment: Thank you so much! I hadn't seen that!

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in using `$1` or any other field inside a `BEGIN{}` block, the `BEGIN` is executed before the file is read so no fields are defined.:

```
$ echo foo | awk 'BEGIN{print "The first field is:", $1}'
The first field is:
```

And there's also no point in having an empty `END{}` block. That said, I think all you want is this:

```
awk '{print "Hello",NR,$0 > "outFile"}' inFile
```

Or, alternatively:

```
awk '{print "Hello",NR,$0}' inFile > outFile
```

If you run the command above on a file like this:

```
$ cat file
field1 field2
field1 field2
field1 field2
field1 field2
field1 field2
```

You will get:

```
$ awk '{print "Hello",NR,$0 > "outFile"}' file
$ cat outFile 
Hello 1 field1 field2
Hello 2 field1 field2
Hello 3 field1 field2
Hello 4 field1 field2
Hello 5 field1 field2
```

In an awk script, that would be:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
    print "Hello",NR,$0 > "outFile"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**$1**, **>** and **>>** are concepts from bash, but the interpreter of your script is /bin/awk (as per the script's first line). IMHO, you could try calling the awk script from inside a bash script, or try using a HEREDOC for having everything inside the same file.

Update: bash/awk here doc example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489995/can-you-use-heredocuments-to-embed-awk-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: `awk` supports redirecting output to both files and external commands.

Comment: I'm curious @Kusalananda. Could you provide a sample?

Comment: My answer contains a sample of redirecting to a file. To redirect to a command, use `print | "some-command"`.  This should be covered by the `awk` manual on your system. Use `"some-command" | getline` to read from a command.