# How can I sort within an awk script on Linux?

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, sort

I have file `fruit` that has the following content:

```
Apples, 12
Pears, 50
Cheries, 7
Strawberries, 36
Oranges, 2
```

I would like to sort the numerical data of the file:

```
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)j+=$i;printf "Fruit %d%s, %d\n",NR,OFS,$1,j | sort -k 2 > "numbers"; j=0"
```

In order to run the awk script I run the command:

```
awk -f numbers fruit
```

The numbers file has the same content as fruit but its 1st and 2nd field are copied to the numbers file.

Comment: Why do you need to sort in awk? Awk doesn't have native sorting capabilities, why don't you just sort the output instead?

Comment: I wanted to see a different approach inside the awk command

Comment: @terdon GNU awk (which I THINK is the default awk on Linux) does have native sorting capabilities.

Comment: @user25 [edit] your question to show the expected output given the input you posted. We can't necessarily tell what you want to do from reading a script that doesn't do whatever it is you want to do. In particular it's not at all clear what `j` is supposed to hold.

Comment: @EdMorton see [their last question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/560115/22222) for some context. And you're quite right! GNU awk has `asort`. I could have sworn it didn't, for some reason. Thanks! Not quite sure if it would be worth it since you'd have to read the entire file into an array and then sort the array, so sorting the output would still likely be more efficient, but it's more than enough for this.

Comment: @terdon It doesn't just have `asort()` it also has the far more useful `sorted_in`, to let you simply define an order for `for (i in array)` to visit the array elements - see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning.I agree that just piping to UNIX sort would be more efficient for this problem though.

Comment: @EdMorton GNU awk is NOT the default in debian and alike. "mawk" is the default, which doesn't have any "asort" builtin function.

Comment: @Ed, Linux is just a kernel, it doesn't have any awk command in itself. Most Linux-based OSes are embedded and will have a busybox awk if they have awk at all, Debian/Ubuntu use some old variant of mawk (which is not even POSIX compliant on many fronts) though it can be replaced with gawk.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas good to know, thanks. Thanks also pizdelect.

Answer (score 10):

GNU awk gives you a neat way to control how you traverse over an array: see [Controlling Array Traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal) and [Controlling Scanning](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning)

```
gawk -F', ' '
    {fruit[$1] = $2}
    END {
        OFS = FS

        printf "\nordered by fruit name\n"
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for (f in fruit) print f, fruit[f]

        printf "\nordered by number\n"
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
        for (f in fruit) print f, fruit[f]
    }
' fruit
```

outputs

```
ordered by fruit name
Apples, 12
Cheries, 7
Oranges, 2
Pears, 50
Strawberries, 36

ordered by number
Pears, 50
Strawberries, 36
Apples, 12
Cheries, 7
Oranges, 2
```

Comment: I know that the documentation says this but this doesn't seem to be working on my CentOS6 (because reasons) server. And also on my MacBook (which I assume doesn't have GNU awk).

Comment: MacOS does not ship with GNU awk, but you can install it  easily with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). For CentOS, what version is installed (`gawk --version`)?

Comment: ```# gawk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2009 Free Software Foundation.```

I assume these cool features are in gawk version 4?

Comment: Yeah, looking at the NOTES in http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/ it looks like this feature was introduced in v4.0. I guess you have to call out to `sort`

Answer (score 3):

You can actually pass awk's `print` through `"sort"` (note the quotes):

```
$ awk '{print "Fruit",NR, $0 | "sort -k 2 -t, -rn"}' fruit 
Fruit 2 Pears, 50
Fruit 4 Strawberries, 36
Fruit 1 Apples, 12
Fruit 3 Cheries, 7
Fruit 5 Oranges, 2
```

So, to write to `numbers`, you can do:

```
awk '{print "Fruit",NR, $0 | "sort -k 2 -t, -rn > numbers"}' fruit
```

Note that I simplified your awk a bit. There's no need to use `printf` here or to explicitly print `OFS` since you aren't changing it anywhere. I also don't see what your `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)j+=$i` is doing. You already have the number with `NR` and your `printf` wasn't using `j` anyway.

Comment: Instead of calling sort inside awk it's simpler and more efficient to simply print in awk and pipe the awk output to sort: `awk '{print ...}' fruit | sort ...`.

Comment: @EdMorton oh, absolutely! I would never use this approach myself, what's the point? But [this is what the OP asked for](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560185/how-can-i-sort-within-an-awk-script-on-linux/560190?noredirect=1#comment1041164_560185).

Comment: I often find a requirement to sort within gawk, when I don't want to sort the whole output. For example, collecting and reporting stats separately for each input file. I can use a decorate/sort/clip method to tailormake simple keys from complex data (e.g. rank electrical equipment overloads using a side array of max ratings). Also, external sort uses disk workfiles, and a split/merge strategy. Internal sort can use better methods.

Comment: @EdMorton @terdon I use this awk sort to sort body lines while leaving the header alone.  `echo -e "HEADER\nline3\nline1\nline2" | awk 'NR<=1 {print} NR > 1 {print | "sort" }'

Comment: @JoeSkora isn't it easier to use a subshell? `(printf 'HEADER'; printf '\nline3\nline1\nline2\n' | sort ) > file`. Or, when sorting a file: `( head -n1 file; tail -n+2 file | sort) > newfile`.

Comment: @JoeSkora you don't need to spawn a subshell from awk and then hope that the buffering from all concerned leads to the output from the subshell getting to stdout after the rest of the output from the awk command instead of before it or, if applicable, in the middle of it. Just do `awk '{print (NR>1), $0}' | sort -k1,1n -k2 | cut -d' ' -f2-`

Comment: @terdon I often use this across multiple SSH hops, so it has to be a single command stream.

Comment: @EdMorton I like printing the conditional, great idea.  The last part can be simplified further leaving this. `awk '{print (NR>1),$0}' | sort ... | cut -c3-`.

Comment: @JoeSkora that's true, there's just usually other fields to operate on too, e.g. also printing `NR` so you can retain original order when there's duplicate key values and you don't have GNU sort for `-s` so it's usually more like `awk '{print (NR>1), NR, $0}' | sort -k1,1n -k3 -k2,2n | cut -d' ' -f3-`

Comment: Despite using awk for nearly a decade I did not know you could do this.  This was great when I needed to redirect part of my output sorted into one file while using it in another way going to another file.

Answer (score 1):

I must have had a serious problem with SunOS nawk in 2002. I found my test script that contained three awk implementations that run within non-GNU awk:

(a) eSort: uses a workfile and reads back through a pipe running sort command. Not good in my case, because I was doing stuff through ssh for agentless monitoring, and external work files were too invasive for our live servers.

(b) qSort: a recursive partition sort. Performance bad for large data, and breaks the stack in mawk for > 2000 elements. Fun to write though.

(c) hSort: a sort-in-situ algorithm in 15 lines. This heap uses an indexing algorithm to support a binary tree (see Wikipedia).

This bash script contains awk functions hSort and hUp which implement the actual sort. One action line puts all the input into an array, and the END block calls hSort and reports the results.

The input data is the contents of "man bash", once as lines, and again as words. We use wc to prove nothing got lost, and sort -c to prove the output is sorted. The timings include the read and print overhead.

This is the test shot:

```
Paul--) ./hSort

Sorted 5251 elements.

real    0m0.120s
user    0m0.116s
sys     0m0.004s
  5251  44463 273728 hSort.raw
sort: hSort.raw:2: disorder: 
  5251  44463 273728 hSort.srt

Sorted 44463 elements.

real    0m1.336s
user    0m1.316s
sys     0m0.008s
 44463  44463 265333 hSort.raw
sort: hSort.raw:3: disorder: Commands
 44463  44463 265333 hSort.srt
```

This is the script. Enjoy!

```
#! /bin/bash

export LC_ALL="C"

#### Heapsort algorithm.

function hSort {    #:: (void) < text

    local AWK='''
#.. Construct the heap, then unfold it.
function hSort (A, Local, n, j, e) {
    for (j in A) ++n;
    for (j = int (n / 2); j > 0; --j) hUp( j, A[j], n, A);
    for (j = n; j > 1; --j) { e = A[j]; A[j] = A[1]; hUp( 1, e, j - 1, A); }
    return (0 + n);
}
#.. Given an empty slot and its contents, pull any bigger elements up the tree.
function hUp (j, e, n, V, Local, k) {
    while ((k = j + j) <= n) {
        if (k + 1 <= n  &&  STX V[k] < STX V[k + 1]) ++k;
        if (STX e >= STX V[k]) break;
        V[j] = V[k]; j = k;
    }
    V[j] = e;
}
{ U[++nU] = $0; }
END {
    sz = hSort( U);
    printf ("\nSorted %s elements.\n", sz) | "cat 1>&2";
    for (k = 1; k in U; ++k) print U[k];
}
'''
    mawk -f <( printf '%s\n' "${AWK}" )
}

#### Test Package Starts Here.

function Test {
    time hSort < hSort.raw > hSort.srt
    for fn in hSort.{raw,srt}; do wc "${fn}"; LC_ALL="C" sort -c "${fn}"; done
}
    AWK_LINE='{ sub (/^[ \011]+/, ""); print; }'
    AWK_WORD='{ for (f = 1; f <= NF; ++f) print $(f); }'

    #xxx : > hSort.raw; Test        #.. Edge cases.
    #xxx echo "Hello" > hSort.raw; Test
    #xxx { echo "World"; echo "Hello"; } > hSort.raw; Test

    man bash | col -b | mawk "${AWK_LINE}" > hSort.raw; Test
    man bash | col -b | mawk "${AWK_WORD}" > hSort.raw; Test
```